# In what cases do open source licenses conditions apply?

Tags: open-source-definition

Apache v2, MIL, GNU, and many others. They all have certain conditions you have to follow. But in what cases? What if I want to use Apache v2 (for example) software that generates... let's say images. And I use these images in a commercial project. I mean I used the software for a commercial purpose. Do the conditions of the OSL apply in such a case?